# How it will work if i solder thin wire with thick wire

Tags: power-supply, connector

I have a simple power supply for a rc airplane. I need to connect the speed controller to my brushless motor. The motor has very thin wires without a connector. But the speed controller has thick wires. I would like to connect them.

Will it heat the wires?

Comment: What are the specs of the motor (voltage, but most importantly current)?

Comment: @jippie  Maybe OP meant `Will they heat?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the limiting point here would be motor wires. I would expect whoever designed the motor to have used appropriate wires on the motor so that the loses in the wires are negligible.

I don't think that in this case it would be a heat problem to connect the speed controller wires to motor wires.

The resistance of wire depends on the length of wire, wire's cross-section and the specific resistance of the wire. The resistance is \$ R= \frac{ \rho l}{A}\$, where A is the area of the cross-section of the wire, l is wire length and \$\rho\$ is specific resistivity of the material. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge) is a handy list of resistances of copper wires using the AWG system. [Here](http://www.centralcables.co.uk/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=OOkqIqIcowI%3D&tabid=68) is a chart with resistances of cables with cross-section expressed in \$mm^2\$.

For exact amount of heat, we'll need the current and the voltage of the motor. The power formula is P=V*I and based on it, we may be able to guess if the wires will heat or not. The exact amount of heat and temperature rise depend on lots of factors such as thermal conductivity between the cable and air and if the cable is being ventilated and so on.

Comment: What this gentleman says. The current drawn at full speed will be limited by the motor. If the motor wires can handle the load, the bigger wires on the controller will not be a problem.

Comment: So thicker wires on the motor is not the problem, because motor defines the current being transfered trough wires. Can be worst if opposite? Am i right?

Comment: @Pol Wait a second! Are the thicker wires on the motor or on the motor controller? If the thick wires are on the motor controller, then you're fine. The controller can provide more current than motor needs and motor will take what it needs. If the thicker wires are on the motor, then you could have the problem.

Comment: It is on motor :) Got it